# Replace all the enters in a text and then replace them all with <br/>

Tags: php

I want to replace the enters in the `$content` part to `<br/>` so it actually shows up as enter on my webs

```
$content = $_POST['thread_content'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$str = $content.split("\n").join("<br />"); 

$co = db::escape($str);
$ti = db::escape($title);
$id = db::escape($_GET['id']);
$user = user::getVar("id");

db::query("INSERT INTO Topics (topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by) VALUES ('".$ti."', '".$date."', '".$id."', '".$user."')");

//ID IS ID VAN HET BOARD! NIET VAN TOPIC ID!
$result = db::query("SELECT * FROM Topics ORDER BY topic_id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $topicid = $row["topic_id"];
    db::query("INSERT INTO Posts (post_content, post_date, post_topic, post_by, post_title, post_board) VALUES ('".$co."', '".$date."', '".$topicid."', '".$user."', '".$ti."', '".$id."')");
    header("Location: ?p=Topics&id=".$topicid);
}
```

?>

But the `$str = $content.split("\n").join("<br/>");` Doesn't work as I want it to work. It doesnt output `<br/>` in the output string to the database. Any one can help me out with this?

Comment: How about `nl2br()`? http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Do you want to replace "\n" with "<br>"

Comment: I want to replace each end of line to a <br/>

Comment: YOu should also post an example string instead of `$content = $_POST['thread_content'];`

Answer (score 1):

[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php) is the function you are looking for.

```
$str = nl2br($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how string splitting and joining work in PHP (you're probably thinking of Python).

The easiest way to do this specific task would be to use PHP's builtin nl2br function instead.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) is quite nice too, have a look.